# Nested MVC communication patterns

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

This is entirely a best practices type question, so the language is irrelevant.  I understand the basic principles of MVC, and that there are different, subtle flavors of it (i.e. views having a direct reference to models vs. a data delegate off the controller).

My question is around cross MVC communication, when those MVCs are nested.  An example of this would be a drawing program (like Paint or something).  The Canvas itself could be an MVC, but so could each drawn entity (e.g. Shapes, Text).  From a model perspective, it makes sense for the `CanvasModel` to have a collection of entities, but should the `CanvasView` and `CanvasController` have corresponding collections of entity views and controllers respectively?

Also, what's the best/cleanest way to add a new drawn entity?  Say the user has the CircleTool active, they click in the Canvas view and start drawing the shape.  The `CanvasView` could fire relevant mouse down/move/up events that the `CanvasController` could listen to.  The controller could then basically proxy those events to the CircleTool (state pattern).  On mouse down, the CircleTool would want to create a new Circle.  Should the Tool create a new `CircleEntityController` outright and call something like `canvasController.addEntity(circleController)`?  Where should the responsibility of creating the Circle's model and view then lie?

Sorry if these questions are somewhat nebulous :)

--**EDIT**--

Here's a pseudo-codish example of what I'm talking about:

```
CircleTool {
    ...
    onCanvasMouseDown: function(x, y) {
        // should this tool/service create the new entity's model, view, and controller?
        var model = new CircleModel(x, y);
        var view = new CircleView(model);
        var controller = new CircleController(model, view);

        // should the canvasController's add method take in all 3 components
        // and then add them to their respective endpoints?
        this.canvasController.addEntity(model, view, controller);
    }
    ...
}


CanvasController {
    ...
    addEntity: function(model, view, controller) {
        // this doesn't really feel right...
        this.entityControllers.add(controller);
        this.model.addEntityModel(model);
        this.view.addEntityView(view);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: you might want to take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

Comment: Where would the Mediator exist for this scenario, and what would it look like?  It seems like it could possibly work, but I'm not quite sure how it fits into the MVC triads.  A mediator really just seems like a Controller (especially in the case of how Apple wants you to use MVC).

Comment: too long, i will post an answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Wow, well I have perhaps a surprising answer to this question: I have a long-standing rant about how MVC is considered this beatific symbol of perfection in programming that no one sees any issues with. A favorite interview question is 'what are some problems, or challenges that you might encounter in MVC?' It's amazing how often the question is greeted with a puzzled, queasy look.

The answer is really quite simple: MVC relies on the notion of multiple consumers having their needs met from a single shared model object. Things really start to go to hell when the various views make different demands. There was an article a few years ago where the authors advanced the notion of Hierarchical MVC. Someone else came on in the comments and told them that what they thought they were inventing already existed: a pattern called Presentation-Abstraction-Controller (PAC). Probably the only place you see this in the pattern literature is in the Buschmann book, sometimes referred to as the Gang of Five, or POSA (Pattern-Oriented Software Architecture). Interestingly, whenever I explain PAC, I use a paint program as the perfect example.

The main difference is that in PAC, the presentation elements tend to have their own models, that's the A of the PAC: for each component, you don't have to, but can have an abstraction. Per some of the other responses here, then what happens is you have a coordinating controller, in this case, that would rule over the canvas. Let's say we want to add a small view to the side of the canvas that shows the count of various shapes (e.g. Squares 3, Circles 5, etc.). That controller would register with the coordinating controller to listen on a two events: elementAdded and elementRemoved. As it received each notification, it would simply update a map it had in its own Abstraction. Imagine how absurd it would be to alter a shared model that a bunch of components are using to add support for such a thing. Furthermore, the person who did the ShapesSummary component didn't have to learn about anything, but the event protocols, and of course all its interactions with collaborators are immutable.

The hierarchical part is that there can be layers of controllers in PAC: for instance, the coordinating one at the Canvas level would not know about any of the various components with specialized behaviors. We might make a shape that can contain other things, which would need logic for accepting drags, etc. That component would have its own Abstraction and Controller, and that Controller would coordinate its activities with the CanvasController, etc. It might even become necessary at some point for it to communicate with its contained components.

Here's the [POSA Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471958697).

Comment: I agree MVC isn't a silver bullet, and it comes with its own set of issues.  In your example, you say "That controller would register with the coordinating controller to listen on a two events: elementAdded and elementRemoved.".  So does the controller completely encapsulate its model and republish/proxy those events for outside controllers to listen to?  I've tried reading up on PAC but haven't really found any good examples.  Do you have an example of a paint program written in PAC?  I'll give you the bounty reward so the points don't go to waste.  I'll have to keep looking into PAC I guess.

Comment: Contact me at rob at ontometrics. I did a paint program in Java (long time ago) and would love to help you. I can help with PAC too. Thanks for picking my answer.

Comment: Answer to encapsulation question yes, and only when/if needed on the republish but you have the idea. Interestingly I am working with Akka right now and the Actor/Agent model is very similar: no shared mutable state and event driven communication amongst a hierarchy of supervised collaborators.

Comment: Really good answer, but thanks especially for the POSA book link.

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic Sure. One of the best patterns books ever. Dude, not to grovel, but give an upvote if you got something from an answer. :)

Comment: Sure! My sincerest apologies for forgetting! :D

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to attack this.  I don't disagree with the other answers posted here.

However, one way that I've done this is by using the observer pattern.  And let me explain why.

The observer pattern is necessary here because these drawing tools are nothing without the canvas.  So, if you have no canvas, you can't (or shouldn't) invoke the circle tool.  So instead, my canvas has a host of observers on it.

Each tool that can be used on the canvas is added as an observable event.  Then, when an event is fired - like "begin draw" - the tool is sent as the context (in this case 'circle').  From there, the actions of the circle tool execute.

Another way to imagine this is that each layer has its own service, model, and view.  The controller really is at the exterior level and associated with the canvas.  So, services are only called by other services or by a controller.  There are no circle tool controllers - so only another service (in our case the observed event) can call it.  That service is responsible for aggregating the data, building the model, and supplying a view.

Comment: The way I have the tools currently set up is pretty similar to that actually.  The CanvasController has an 'activeTool', that implements an interface containing methods like 'onClick', 'onMouseMove', etc...  and on such events the active tool's methods are called.  The part I'm struggling with is how the tool services add new drawn entities.  Since the each part of the Canvas MVC triad has it's own collection of entities (e.g. CanvasController has a list of WidgetControllers, CanvasView has a list of WidgetViews).  Does the tool service create all 3 of the widget MVC classes and add them?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain if I follow the question... but let me see.  I would think the best result on this is that the 'active tool' is actually the service for that tool.  You can strip down some of the MVC in this case.  There is no need for a controller here - because the service already has those methods ( from the interface ) that you described.  Your canvas controller is already calling them, so there should be no "child" controller.  As for the associated view, I've never been too sure - I generally invoke the "magical" (heh) "helper class" which automagically interprets view creation.

Comment: I updated my original question to include a pseudo-codish example.  The CircleTool doesn't have it's own completely separate MVC if that's what you were referring to.  I may end up just using some kind of "magical" helper class haha...  Hoping to find some kind of approach that feels better though.

Answer (score 0):

The `RenderingService` *(for lack of better name - the thing that manages the interaction of shapes)* would instantiate new `Circle` [domain object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) and informs about it *(either directly or when view is requesting new data)* the view.

It seems that you are still in a habit of dumping all your application logic (interaction between storage abstractions and domain objects) in the presentation layer (in your case - the controllers).

P.S. I am assuming that you are not talking about HMVC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Where does this `RenderingService` class exist?  Does the `CanvasController` delegate directly to it for creating new entities (their model, view, and controller)?  I don't really understand.  I've also never heard of HMVC before.

Comment: Services in general are the "public API" of model layer. You should access them via service factory in the views and controllers.

Comment: I'm still not following, could you point me towards a link or something that goes into more details?  Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Although the point made in this answer has merit, I don't think the answer itself is particularly good/helpful. People ask these questions because they are inexperienced. From this sort of fragmented information, it is completely impossible to draw a clear picture of 'how things could be done properly'.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, but consider if the mediator pattern is applicable.

From [the gang of four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns):

> ### Intent
>
> Define an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact.
>   Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to
>   each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction
>   independently.
>
> ### Applicability
>
> Use the Mediator pattern when
>
> 1. a set of objects communicate in well-defined but complex ways. The resulting interdependencies are unstructured and difficult to
>      understand.
> 2. reusing an object is difficult because it refers to and communicates with many other objects.
> 3. a behavior that's distributed between several classes should be customizable without a lot of subclassing.
>
> ### Consequences
>
> The Mediator pattern has the following benefits and drawbacks:
>
> - It limits subclassing. A mediator localizes behavior that otherwise would be distributed among several objects. Changing this
>     behavior requires subclassing Mediator only; Colleague classes can be
>     reused as is.
> - It decouples colleagues. A mediator promotes loose coupling between colleagues. You can vary and reuse Colleague and Mediator classes independently.
> - It simplifies object protocols. A mediator replaces many-to-many interactions with one-to-many interactions between the mediator and
>     its colleagues. One-to-many relationships are easier to understand,
>     maintain, and extend.
> - It abstracts how objects cooperate. Making mediation an independent concept and encapsulating it in an object lets you focus
>     on how objects interact apart from their individual behavior. That can
>     help clarify how objects interact in a system.
> - It centralizes control. The Mediator pattern trades complexity of interaction for complexity in the mediator. Because a mediator
>     encapsulates protocols, it can become more complex than any individual
>     colleague. This can make the mediator itself a monolith that's hard to
>     maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not quite sure how wire up a mediator for the scenario I described though :(

Comment: me neither, i just thought it would ring a bell. the gof book say: "MVC supports nested views with the CompositeView class, a subclass of View. CompositeView objects act just like View objects; a composite view can be used wherever a view can be used, but it also contains and manages nested views.", so maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578312/mvc-difference-between-two-step-and-composite-view-patterns or http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ModelViewControllerAsAnAggregateDesignPattern would give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would opt for Composite pattern when working with shapes. Regardless of whether you have circles, squares, rectangles, triangles, letters, etc, I would treat everything as a shape. Some shapes can be simple shapes like lines, other shapes can be more complex composite shapes like graphs, pie charts, etc. A good idea would be to define a base class that has a reference to basic shapes and to advanced (complex) shapes. Both basic shapes and advanced shapes are the same type of object, its just that advanced shapes can have children that help define this complex object.

By following this logic, you can use the logic where each shape draws itself and each shape knows its location, and based on that you would apply certain logic and algorithm to ask which shape was clicked and each shape could respond to your event.

According to the [GoF book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612):

### Intent

Compose objects into tree structures to represent part-whole hierarchies. Composite lets clients treat individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly.

### Motivation

Graphics applications like drawing editors and schematic capture systems let users build complex diagrams out of simple components. The user can group components to form larger components. [...]

The key to composite pattern is an abstract class that represents *both* primitives and their containers. For the graphics system, this class is Graphics. Graphic declares operations like Draw that are specific to graphical objects. It also declares operations that all composite objects share, such as operations for accessing and managing its children.

Now, back to your problem. One of the base functions, as previously mentioned, is a `Draw` method. This method could be implemented as an abstract method in the base class with a following signature:

```
public virtual void Draw(YourDrawingCanvas canvas);
```

Each shape would implement it's own version of Draw. The argument that you pass them is a reference to the drawing canvas where each shape will draw itself. Each shape could store a reference of itself in its internal structure and it can be used to compare mouse click location with these coordinates to inform you which shape was clicked.

Comment: Would this `Draw` method be on the shape model subclasses (e.g. Line, Rectangle)?  So the Tool subclasses would create their corresponding Shape's model, and call `Draw()`, but then what creates the Shape's View/Controller?  The method/verb `Draw` implies that it should create the view representing that Shape, but the model isn't supposed to know anything about the view.

Comment: If you are going to create an interface or an abstract class, I would put the Draw method there and have it implemented/specialized in classes which implement the interface or which override the method in the abstract class.

Comment: Where does the responsibility for creating the view/controller then lie?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view using nested MVC components is kind of an overkill here: At each point in time the model contains multiple elements (different circles, squares etc., which may be nested constructs using the Composite pattern, as mentioned in another answer).  *However, the canvas that displays the elements is just a single view*! 
(And corresponding to the single view there would only a single controller be needed.)

One case of having several views could be a list of elements (which is shown, e.g., next to the canvas) - then you could implement the canvas and the element list as two distinct views on one and the same model.

Regarding the question of how to "best" implement adding an element: I would consider the following sequence of events:

- The view notifies its listeners that a new circle element has been drawn (with the middle point and an initial radius as parameters, for example).
- The controller is registered as listener to the view, so the controller's "draw-circle(point, radius)" listener method is invoked.
- The controller creates a new circle instance in the model (either directly, or via a factory class which is part of the model - I think there are lots of different ways of implementing the creation of new elements). *The controller is "in control" (literally), so I believe that it's the controllers responsibility to instantiate a new element (or at least trigger the instantiation)*.
- In the model, some kind of "add element" method is invoked by the previous step.
- The model raises a "new element created" notification to all of its listeners (probably passing on a reference to the newly created element).
- The canvas is registered as listener to the model, so the canvas' "new element created (element)" listener method is invoked.
- As response to the latter notification, the canvas draws the circle (on itself).

Comment: Does it still seem like overkill if the application needs to support selecting, moving, resizing, and rotating these shapes after they've been drawn?  I probably could've mentioned that in the original post, but all the possible post-drawing interaction that can happen is why I chose to go with nested MVCs.  Also, in the example you described, does the control contain methods for every possible shape it can draw?

Comment: I'll tackle the second question first: _Does the controller contain methods for every possible shape?_ This depends on how to want to implement it. If there is a fixed (low) number of shapes, you could implement it that way. Otherwise, the view could raise a general "shape creation" event, with e.g. an enumeration value for the shape type (circle, square, etc) and the middle point. The controller could forward the creation request to the model, and let the model figure out the concrete class of shape to be instantiated.

Comment: Regarding the different interactions: If the controller contains one listener method for every interaction, I still don't see a forcing reason for using multiple MVC constructs.

Answer (score 0):

*I am assuming MSPaint-like behavior, where the active tool creates a vector graphic glyph that the user can manipulate until he's satisfied. When the user is satisfied, the glyph gets written to the image, which is a raster of pixels.*

---

When the Circle Tool gets selected, I'd have the CanvasController deselect the previously active tool's MVC trio (if another tool was active) and create a new CircleToolController, CircleModel and CircleView. The previously active glyph becomes final and draws itself to the CanvasModel.

The CanvasView will need to be passed a reference to the CircleView so it can draw the CanvasModel's pixels to the screen before the Circle gets drawn. The actual drawing of the circle to the screen, I'd delegate to the CircleView.

The CircleView will therefore need to know and observe other, more general, model classes besides the CircleModel, I'm thinking of a color selection / palette model, and a model for fill style and line thickness, etc. These other models live as long as the application does and have their own View and Controller. They are quite separate of the rest of the application after all.

---

As a sidenote: You could actually split off the drawing of the CanvasModel (the raster of pixel colors) by the CanvasView from the coordination of the updating of the entire screen. Have a higher level PaintView which knows the CanvasView and the active GlyphView (for example the CircleView) coordinate the drawing between the CanvasView and the GlyphView.

Comment: So in this scenario does the CanvasController know about every type of Tool that could be activated?

Comment: I'd expect the different Glyph-MVC classes to implement GlyphModel, GlyphView, GlyphToolController interfaces. Then a factory can create them for a given Glyph tool type. But I'd make it the CanvasController's job to call the factory methods and pass around the appropriate references.